# avoiding writing loops

Tags: functions, infinite-loop

I have a list

```
a={1,2,3,4,5}
```

I want to calculate absolute differences of each element with all other elements

```
 b={{0,1,2,3,4},{1,0,1,2,3},{2,1,0,1,2},{3,2,1,0,1},{4,3,2,1,0}}
```

and then calculate the total for each subarray

```
  c={10,7,6,7,10}
```

I want to write it in one line basically, need help here

```
 b=[#1-a]&/@a  isn't working.
```

Do someone has an easy way to write it out, instead of using any module loop? thanks in advance

Comment: What are those naked square brackets for? `[]` used for passing arguments to functions (e.g. `Abs`), you almost got it: `Abs[#1 - a] & /@ a`.

Comment: I hope that you're just running an experiment in trying to learn Mathematica, because what you're trying to do is already implemented as a function: `CentralFeature[a]`. For graphs it's `GraphCenter[g]` and for geometric data `SpatialMedian[a]` (not necessarily a point in your set, though in your example it would have been 3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Total@Outer[Abs[#1 - #2] &, a, a]
```

Comment: I voted this one for this is the simplest!ddd

Comment: Thanks.  I went through several alternatives but liked it best myself!  `Outer` is extremely powerful.

Answer (score 7):

```
Total[DistanceMatrix[a]]
```

...too short to be an acceptable answer (minimum is 30 characters) without some meaningless commentary

Answer (score 2):

is this code golf?
(cause I lost...)

```
s=Length@a;Plus@@Table[Abs[a[[i]]-a[[j]]],{j, s},{i, s}]
```

Comment: You didn't complete the task, which is to calculate the total of each sub-array.

Comment: you are right! I "totally" forgot it

Answer (score 2):

Avoid 1 loop:

```
 Total[Abs[a - # & /@ a]]
```

Avoid both loops:

```
 Total[Abs[ConstantArray[a, Length[a]] - a]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(*Method 1*)
Total@Outer[Abs@*Plus, a, -a]

(*Method 2*)
Permutations[a, {2}]. {1, -1} // Plus @@@ Abs@Partition[#, 4] &
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Distribute[{{a}, a}, List, List, List, Total@Abs[#1 - #2] &]
```

> {10, 7, 6, 7, 10}